# Is there a good way to load data from BigQuery into Clickhouse quickly?

Tags: google-bigquery, clickhouse

I'm working on a tool which will load the results of a BigQuery query into Clickhouse for further analysis. Is there a common pattern to get data from a BigQuery table into Clickhouse fast?

So far it seems my best bet is a writing a custom tool to read the data out of the query results table using the google bigquery storage api, write it to disk as AVRO and then load it into clickhouse.

I just wanted to check if there are any good alternatives before I spend time on it. The most important factor for me is the time from query completion to data in clickhouse.

Comment: instead of avro, maybe better will compressed TSV

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use [airbyte](https://airbyte.com/) or [double.cloud](https://double.cloud/services/doublecloud-transfer). The last one have also managed clickhouse as service.